# Error while processing the regular expression in NLP text pre-processing

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to do the text pre-processing in NLP, but am encountering following error while implementing
following is the code:

```
    corpus=[] 
    for i in range (len(message)):
    text=re.sub('[^a-zA-z]',' ',message['title'][i])
    text=text.lower()
    text=text.split()
    text=[lem.lemmatize(word) for word in text if word not in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    text=' '.join(text)
    corpus.append(text)
```

above code is getting the following error in python

```
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
```

KeyError: 6

But the same code is getting executed when executed not in for loop:

```
   text1=re.sub('[^a-zA-z]',' ',message['title'][0])
```

Am getting Output for this above code but in loop it is throwing the error.
Any leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you run it outside the loop, you're accessing `message['title'][0]` but inside the loop, when `i` takes the value `6`, you try to access `message['title'][6]` which is raising that error. That means that `message['title']` does not have that key.

You should double check what you're trying to access and if you should use the iterator in that place, or check the bounds of the for loop (`range(len(message))`) because that might not be what you want.